# How to go to top of the screen with ref react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-ref

how can i go to the top of the screen or other element in the screen with  react-native ?
i need to use ref for that ?

**note that i have scroll view from outside, so i Cant use scroll view methods**

little of my code:

```
                <AnimatedButton
                onPress={() => console.log("check", myref.current)}

                icon="arrow-up"
            />
        )}
```

and i want to go for example to the first element in the screen:

```
<View ref={myref}>
                <Text style={styles.massagetitle}>בחר סוג טיפול</Text>
            </View>
```

how to handle that without scrollView ?? (again, because i cant put scroll view because i have scroll view from outside wrap it)

Comment: try to create the ref the following way through arrow function, ref={(ref) => { this.scrollRef= ref; }}, then utilize it inside a press event, this.scrollRef..scrollTo({x: 0, y: 200, animated: true})

Comment: @Decoder1.618034 Why `y: 200`?

Comment: U can show me example on my code? Ita possible  to  do it without the scroll view?

Comment: You can just replace it with whatever y value you want, in your case it can be 0, if you want to see a full example please let me know

Comment: yes, i want please. because im trying that without the scrollView and get a lot of errors...